# Vb.net how to search in listview?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image]

Can anyone help me on how to search for the last word in the column or even the word that is in the column?

This is my code but this not enough to search the other word in the column.

```vb
Dim listitems As ListViewItem
Dim datareader As MySqlDataReader
Dim str As String = "select * from sample where sample like @1 '%' "
cmd = New MySqlCommand(str, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBox1.Text)
datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader
ListView1.Items.Clear()
While (datareader.Read())
    listitems = ListView1.Items.Add(datareader("id"))
    listitems.SubItems.Add(datareader("sample"))
End While
datareader.Close()
```

Comment: `PLEASE HELP ME!`  Do you think anyone posts here who *doesnt* need help? No idea what `other word in the column` means but sounds like a simple SQL composition thing.  A DGV would be a far better choice - no need to run new SQL - just filter the datasource

Comment: what i mean is on how i can search all word from the column. sorry for my English and sorry because im just a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Put % at beginning and end for any word in the column.

Put % at beginning for last word in the column.

```
Dim listitems As ListViewItem
Dim datareader As MySqlDataReader
Dim str As String = "select * from sample where sample like '%' + @1 + '%'"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(str, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBox1.Text)
datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader
ListView1.Items.Clear()
While (datareader.Read())
   listitems = ListView1.Items.Add(datareader("id"))
   listitems.SubItems.Add(datareader("sample"))
End While
datareader.Close()
```

Comment: The `%` must be put directly in the query string. If you put it in the value of the `@1` parameter (like you do now) it will become escaped, thus literally searching for `%keyword`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea it was really help